# How to prevent the wrong StopIteration from being caught?

Tags: python, iterator

Is there a way to prevent `StopIteration` exceptions from being thrown from unrelated code (without having to catch them manually)?

Example: `loop_all` wants to loop through the `myiter` iterator and simply move on when this one has finished. This works unless `some_dangerous_method` or any other code in `myiter` raises a `StopIteration`.

```
def loop_all():
    myiter = myiter()
    try:
        while True:
            next(myiter) # <- I want exactly the StopIteration from this next method
    except StopIteration:
        pass

def myiter():
    some_dangerous_method() # what if this also raises a StopIteration?
    for i in some_other_iter():
        # here may be more code
        yield
```

Is there a way to make it clear to which `StopIteration` the code should react to?

Comment: Why do you think you will ever get a `StopIteration` from somewhere else? That's like expecting a random stdlib call such as getting the current time or a random number to fail...

Comment: This is a real-life example but admittedly, I’d never thought of something like this to occur.

Comment: Also, there are several methods which call third-party code. I don’t want to do a catch all unless there is really, really no other way.

Comment: Is this a real problem? Have you actually had other's `StopIteration` being caught by your code?  Also, are you sure you need to catch it at all?  Why not use a for loop to iterate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function you are calling is invoking next(iter), and isn't dealing with `StopIteration`, then that function has a bug.  Fix it.

Comment: As I’ve written above, the function is calling third-party code which may invode `next(iter)`. It is supposed to crash the whole thing in that case and not have it behave in a strange way.

Comment: If the third party code is raising `StopIteration`, then you are out of luck.  There is no way to distinguish which iteration is ending.  Get the third-party code fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something but why not simply this:

```
def myiter():
    try:
        some_dangerous_method()
    except StopIteration:
        pass # or raise a different exception
    for i in some_other_iter():
        # here may be more code
        yield
```

Comment: This is more of a fix than a solution.

Comment: @Debilski A more complete solution is to create your own wrapper class that individually wraps every necessary method of the dangerous class with appropriate safeguards.